# Can I say, for example "Georgia and its famous children"

Tags: word-choice

In my native language, Georgian, you can say for example "Georgia and its famous children/sons/daughters." The meaning of "children" here is people who were born and/or raised in Georgia and became famous irrespective of whether they continued living in Georgia or moved elsewhere. I want to express this idea similarly in English, but I'm not sure if "Georgia's famous children" sounds natural in English. What's the best way of expressing this idea? "Its famous inhabitants" does not exactly fit for purpose because "inhabitant" may be a newcomer living in Georgia, not originally from Georgia.
My main question is: Does "Georgia's famous children" sound normal in English?
If it does not, then what is the best approximation?

Comment: It's a bit old-fashioned, and millennials or people who don't read much might think you are talking about actual Georgian children.

Comment: Agreed.  "Famous sons and daughters" might be better, because *children* usually means "young children".

Comment: Emigrés from Britain to colonial lands during the Empire period were sometimes called 'Britannia's children', and they were often said, in propaganda, to be rallying to the 'motherland' from 1914 to 1918. Like I said, old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence is typical enough that it will most likely be understood in-context.  (i.e. "Georgia's Famous Children" might be ambiguous as movie title, but it would be perfectly understood in a long speech about Georgia's diaspora.)

However, the word *"child"/"children"* is quite likely to be misunderstood as a literal descriptor of age in a low-context situation.  There are ways that different word choice and sentence structure can make things more clear (e.g. *"Georgian children"* implies literal school-age children, *"children of Georgia"* evokes a more figurative meaning) but these can be somewhat subjective and tricky (e.g. *"famous children of Georgia"* again sounds more literal).  As such, it might make sense to use the slightly more cumbersome *"Georgia's famous sons and daughters"* to remove some of the age-based assumptions loaded onto the word *"child"*.

If you are looking for an alternative phrasing that will be better understood by native-English speakers, then there are a number of other options:

- **"famous Georgians"** - This is the most idiomatic/natural option and additionally is very clear and concise.  Unfortunately (depending on your needs), this phrasing does lose all figurative connotations of "paternal/national pride" that might be evoked with a different phrasing.
- **"Georgia's famous scions"** - This wording is better if you want to evoke strong figurative feelings.  Unfortunately, it's a relatively rare wording/phrasing and thus it might sound a bit stilted depending on the feel of the surrounding contextual material. (i.e. it would be good in a president's speech, but strange in a first-grader's book report.)
- **"Georgia's famous progeny"** - Using *"progeny"* instead of *"children"* should remove most/all of the age ambiguity while leaving the rest of the meaning clear.  This would be much less idiomatic than *"famous Georgians"* but could better evoke figurative implications depending on the surrounding context (while being somewhat less stilted/strange than *"scions"*).

---

*(I am an American born and raised in the midwest; native British speakers might very well have differing views on some of these word choices.)*

Comment: Technically, a 'scion' is a a descendant of a notable family, and I would avoid 'progeny' because it means 'a descendant or the descendants of a person, animal, or plant'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In a very strict literal sense you might be correct.  But, if you scroll through some examples sentences, like at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progeny#examples you should see that these kinds of figurative usages are not too uncommon; and I'd argue the same to be true for 'scion'.

Answer (score 0):

Gamarjobat!

In English, the phrases "Georgia and its famous [children/sons/daughters]" are somewhat unnatural, at least to my American ear. The first option in particular ("Georgia and its famous children") is likely to be interpreted literally: famous children from Georgia. The other two options are somewhat less confusing, and may be understood by older, more well-read readers, but they still sound like literal translations of a non-English phrase and may confuse some readers. However, you could use the stock phrase "**sons and daughters**;" this keeps some of the feeling of the Georgian phrase and is likely to be understood by a wider audience:

> Georgia and its famous sons and daughters.

If you want to keep the structure "Georgia and its famous ___", but avoid *sons*/*daughters* you could use *people*; this is very likely to be understood, but you might find it a bit too dry. If you are talking about a specific group of famous people (e.g. actors, musicians, etc.) using a more specific term might be a good idea.

There are also many other ways to represent this idea:

> Georgia and famous Georgians 
> Famous Georgians and their [country/homeland] 
> Georgia and its most famous people

Comment: @JamesK - I once read an article about opposing team captains hugging in cricket (it was a new thing in the 1980s and 1990s) where the Queensland captain said that he would 'bring his knee up' if a 'nasty sweaty Victorian' tried to put his arms around him.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you may have commented this on the wrong answer lol

Comment: James K had a comment here about being confused between of 'Victorians' (people alive in the UK 1837-1901) and residents of the Australian state of Victoria. It's gone since I posted that comment.